# Populating DataGriView/ComboBox Parameterized MySQL AES_ENCRYPT / AES_DECRYPT

Tags: vb.net

Still moving to MySQL AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT with Parameterized Queries, I finished translating many parts of the code like: INSERT, SELECT, UPDATES, etc. for textboxes and labels. By now I need some orientation to Populating DataGridViews and ComboBoxes with MySQL Parameterized Query.

e.g.

```
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(`AG_Nom`, '" & MyPass & "') AS @UserName, AES_DECRYPT(`AG_Pic`, '" & MyPass & "') AS @UserPic FROM `Agents`"
```

Or if possible use something:

```
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM `Agents`"
```

With AES_DECRYPT and Parameterized values to fill the controls

I tried many unsuccessfully options; my biggest question is how to pass the content of @Varibles to populate the controls.

The follow code not works:

```
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(`AG_Nom`, '" & MyPass & "') AS @UserName, AES_DECRYPT(`AG_Pic`, '" & MyPass & "') AS @UserPic FROM `Agents`"
MySQLConn.Open()

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyPass", AESPass)

Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader())
DataGridView3.DataSource = dt

MySQLConn.Close()
MySQLConn.Dispose()
```

The old way works, of course, show undecrypted string:

```
 MySQLConn.Open()
 Dim dt As New DataTable()
 dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
 DataGridView3.DataSource = dt
 MySQLConn.Close()
```

I would appreciate your feedback to keep improving my code.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question!

```
Dim SQL As String = "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(`AG_Nom`, '" & MyPass & "') AS @UserName, AES_DECRYPT(`AG_Pic`, '" & MyPass & "') AS @UserPic FROM `Agents`"
Dim command = New MySqlCommand(SQL, MySQLConn)
MySQLConn.Open()

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyPass", MyPass)

Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
While Reader.Read
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Reader.GetString("UserName"), Reader.GetString("UserPic"))
End While

MySQLConn.Close()
MySQLConn.Dispose()
```

I hope this help to many other developers
:)